# How to group by with left function (sql) on django?

Tags: sql, django, group-by, substring

I have a table with a column that has the period in this format:

```
vcPeriodo
201801
201801
201802
201802
201802
```

Model:

```
class Trapptoinflacion(models.Model):
    vcperiodo = models.CharField(db_column='vcPeriodo', primary_key=True, max_length=6)
```

So what i want to do is one of this query sql to django:

```
SELECT LEFT(vcPeriodo,4) Anio FROM dbo.traPptoInflacion GROUP BY LEFT(vcPeriodo,4)


SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(vcPeriodo,4) Anio FROM dbo.traPptoInflacion
```

Right now i have this:

```
Trapptoinflacion.objects.values(anio =Substr('vcperiodo', 1, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution:

```
Trapptoinflacion.objects.values(anio =Substr('vcperiodo', 1, 4)).distinct()
```